# How to write a file from a script started by start-job

Tags: powershell

I am using start-job to run a powershell script from another.
The problem is that the script called writes to an  outfile log, but it doesn't write after the caller script is finished.

I mean:

1. script1 calls script2 (with start-job sentence).
2. script2 write into an out-put file in its first line but we cannot see these changes yet in this file.
3. script2 ends.
4. script1 ends.
5. Finally we can see what script 2 wrote into output file.

It is like it keeps the writting until the caller script has ended.

There is a way to write from script2 (called) immediately? Don't want to wait until script1 (caller) is finished.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm unclear on what you're asking. A background job can write to files anytime. How can script2 write into an output file _after_ it has ended? Are you experiencing _buffering_ issues? Please update your question to clarify.

Comment: I've tried to explain a bit better. Maybe is about a buffering issues as you said... Script 2 shoulf write just when is called, but I can't see the changes after a while...

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to run script2 as a background job. Script1 is sleeping for 10 seconds (for use-case), and script2 is writing to the output.log before script1 ends. Please update the path of the scripts below.

**Script1.ps1:**

```
# script1.ps1 
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    # Run script2
    C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\tests\script2.ps1
}

Wait-Job $job

# Get the final output after the job has completed
$output = Receive-Job $job

# Script1 is sleeping 10 secs, script2 wrote to the output.log independent of script1
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10

Remove-Job $job
```

**Script2.ps1:**

```
# script2.ps1
# Write output to the log file
try {
    "Output from script2" | Out-File -Append -FilePath "C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\tests\output.log"
}
catch {
    Write-Host "Error writing to file: $_"
}
```

**Run:**

```
.\script1.ps1
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: The problem is that I cannot wait for script2 to finish. I have tried using scriptblock (i was using filepah), and I have same result.

Comment: Script2 does not wait for the caller's (Script1) end to write the output file. You mentioned above "There is a way to write from script2 (called) immediately? Don't want to wait until script1 (caller) is finished." I don't know that you run the code above directly. If you didn't run it, please run it. Because the above code behaves what u are defining: Script1 calls script2. Script2 writes output immediately without waiting for Script1 to finish. If you say still wrong, maybe I misunderstood..

Comment: I have tried it and I have same output as you, but anything is written in output.log

Comment: On my setup, it is written (above the print screen). I updated script2 to catch an error. Please try to run Powershell with Admin privileges, maybe there is a file write permission issue (I run it on my Desktop). Normally, it should give output.